# Using a Server Component from a Client Components in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I have a problem to solve, concerning the way to use a client component in combination with a server component, in a Next.JS app.

Here is the contents of the file app/page.tsx:

```
/* Below SentenceDisplayMng is a client component
  and SentenceList is a server component. */

import SentenceDisplayMng from './components/SentenceDisplayMng'
import SentenceList from './components/SentenceList'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="z-10 w-full max-w-5xl items-center justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
        <SentenceDisplayMng>
          <SentenceList showFlag={1} />
        </SentenceDisplayMng>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Here is the contents of the file components/SentenceDisplayMng.tsx:

```
'use client'
    
import {useState} from "react";
import TranslatChoice from "./TranslatChoice";
import "./SentenceDisplayMng.css";
    
    
export default function SentenceDisplayMng(
    {children}:{children:React.ReactNode}) {
    const [transType, setTransType] = useState(1)
    const [typeChecks, setTypeChecks] = useState([false,false])
    
    return <div>
        <TranslatChoice
            actionFunc={(v) => setTransType(v)} 
            radChecks={typeChecks} />
        {children}
    </div>
} /* End of SentenceDisplayMng */
```

The way it is currently working is that the component SentenceList is always eventually called the same way (meaning with: showFlag={1}) in the code above. But what I want is to customize the behavior of SentenceList by giving it a showFlag of my choice based on which value is going to be set in TranslatChoice (radio button) by the user.

How should I change the code in SentenceDisplayMng for that to happen?